# Android Galaxy S4 v html radio buttons

Tags: android, html, radio-button, galaxy

The following html form works fine on Chrome, FF, even IE and  IOS, and an old Android jellyBean tablet; on Galaxy S4 phones, however, the radio buttons will not check or work. A small orange square highlights around the button to show it has been tapped, but the button is not checked and the value is not passed.

```
    <form id="build_01" name="build_01" action="designer.php" method="POST">
     <p><input type="radio" name="color" value="auNaturel" required>&nbsp;<img src="images/colors/sm_au_naturel.jpg" align="middle">&nbsp;Au Naturel  </p>      
     <p><input type="radio" name="color" value="black">&nbsp;<img src="images/colors/sm_black_leather.jpg" align="middle">&nbsp; Black Leather  </p>
     <p><input type="radio" name="color" value="red">&nbsp;<img src="images/colors/sm_red_leather.jpg" align="middle">&nbsp; Red Leather  </p>            
    </form>
```

Can anyone help by a) explaining why this would be the case; and b) how to fix it? Any help would be appreciated. I haven't been able to find a question on the subject of Android/Galaxy radio button, but I can't believe I'm the only one to have encountered this issue.

The full form is on this page if you want to look at it: http://www.snowyriverbelts.com.au/designer.php

Thanks in advance.

Update: Thanks to Mike.M for checking. It seems the problem a) is actually two problems; and b) one of which relates to old Android browsers.

Firstly, the new problem, it would appear, relates to the js script that changes the src attributes of the images displayed at the bottom of the form (on everything but old Galaxies). I can't see why that would be a problem when it works elsewhere, but as it relates to the script (I think), I'll post that as a new question.

There are still some quirks regarding the performance of radio buttons on Galaxy Android however.
Tested on Android 2.13, the buttons select the chosen value and pass it to an email with no problem - and the buttons change to show which one is selected.

Tested in Android 4.12, however, the buttons do not change to show which one has been selected. They do actually work in that they select the value and pass it on when tapped, but you can't see what's been done.

Tested in Android 4.3, the buttons change and pass the value no worries. However, the script that changes the source of the images in response to the values selected is not working (which is why I thought the buttons were not passing values). But the script doesn't work on any of the Galaxy phones tested (and they're old ones - all I have access to). But as I say, that'll be another question.

Tested on Android 4.4.2 (on a tablet), both the buttons and the script work fine, btw.
Thanks.

Comment: All of the radio buttons on that page work just fine on my Galaxy S4 running KitKat 4.4.4. I checked in Chrome, Dolphin, and the stock browser.

Comment: Thanks for taking the trouble, Mike M. Did you notice if the img changed at the bottom of the form when the "Build" button was hit?

Comment: [Yep.](http://imgur.com/RqEtU8u)